# Wordpress Widget form function

Tags: php, wordpress, widget

I have this 2 functions in my Wordpress Widget, but I cannot get the form function to get the default or saved values of the widget options.

```
private static function get_defaults() {
    $defauls = array(
            'title' => '' , 
            'subtitle' => '' ,
            'columns' => '4' ,
            'ntax' => '' ,
            'showposts' => '12' ,
            'imagesize' => 'medium' ,
            'posttype' => '' ,
            'exclude' => '' ,
            'terms' => '' ,
            'border' => '' ,
            'padding' => ''
        );

    return $defaults;
}
/**
 * Generates the administration form for the widget.
 *
 * @param array instance The array of keys and values for the widget.
 */
public function form( $instance ) {
    $instance = wp_parse_args(
        (array)$instance,self::get_defaults()
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand what you're trying to achieve but to build a widget please follow the [Widget API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Widgets_API).

**To get the values of a specific widget "option" / attribute, you'll have to use `$instance`. For example, you're trying to get the title of the widget:**

```
$instance['title']
```

If you're trying to get the widget's title in the form function, use:

```
 /**
 * Generates the administration form for the widget.
 *
 * @param array instance The array of keys and values for the widget.
 */
public function form( $instance ) {
    $title = ! empty( $instance['title'] ) ? $instance['title'] : __( 'New title', 'text_domain' );
);
```

What you're doing instead, is to override `$instance` with some args.

To learn more please consider to do some tutorials:

[1: How To Build WordPress Widgets Like A Pro](http://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/how-to-build-wordpress-widgets-like-a-pro/)

[2: How to Create a Custom WordPress Widget](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-create-a-custom-wordpress-widget/)